# How can I send HTTP broadcast message with tornado?

Tags: python-2.7, http, tornado, broadcast

I have a `tornado` HTTP server.

How can I implement `broad-cast` message with the `tornado` server?

Is there any function for that or I just have to send normal HTTP message all clients looping.

I think if I send normal HTTP message, the server should wait for the response.

It seems not the concept of `broad-cast`.

Otherwise, I need another third-part option for `broad-cast`?

Please give me any suggestion to implement `broad-cast` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you might be interested in WebSockets. Tornado seems to have support for this.

Longer answer: I assume you're referring to broadcast from the server to all the clients.
Unfortunately that's not doable conceptually in HTTP/1.1 because of the way it's thought out. The client asks something of the server, and the server responds, independently of all the others.

Furthermore, while there is no request going on between a client and a server, that relationship can be said to not exist at all. So if you were to broadcast, you'd be missing out on clients not currently communicating with the server.

Granted, things are not as simple. Many clients keep a long-lived TCP connection when talking to the server, and pipeline HTTP requests for it on that. Also, a single request is not atomic, and the response is sent in packets. People implemented server-push/long-polling before WebSockets or HTTP/2 with this approach, but there are better ways to go about this now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in idea of a broadcast message in Tornado. The websocket chat demo included with Tornado demonstrates how to loop over the list of clients sending a message to each:

```
def send_updates(cls, chat):
    logging.info("sending message to %d waiters", len(cls.waiters))
    for waiter in cls.waiters:
        try:
            waiter.write_message(chat)
        except:
            logging.error("Error sending message", exc_info=True)
```

See https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py